# SQL: ALL operator and max

Tags: sql, group-by, max

I don't understand why `ALL` operator with `>=` operator returns the max value; for example on a book I found

```
 select S.surname as surname, S.name as name, count(P1.id) as counting 
 from S join P as P1 on S.cf=P1.cf 
 group by S.name, S.surname having count(P1.id)>= ALL
 ( 
     select count(P2.id) from P as P2 group by P2.CF 
 )
```

I understand that  `a > ALL (1,2,3)` returns true if  `a` is greater than 3 because I'll get `true`  if `a` is greater than all elements in my list;
but with `>=` I have 'greater OR equal' so what is the meaning of ' `a` is greater or equal of all elements in my list'? for example `3>=ALL(1,2,3)` is not greater than ALL the elements in my list, and it isn't equal to ALL elements in my list, so it doesn't satisfy the condition, so why that query should return the max i.e. 3?

**update**
the book where I found this behavior is this
https://books.google.it/books/about/Sistemi_di_basi_di_dati_e_applicazioni.html?id=ObenCgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false
the preview at page 143 shows an example of what I'm saying

Comment: The query, as you wrote it, won't run on most databases (perhaps on MySQL).  Please edit your question and show the actual query you ran, and tell us which database you are using.

Comment: this is just a book that describe sql language. The only reference that I found that talks about it is https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/all-any-some-comparison-conditions-in-sql
I would understand that this is an error in the book or my misunderstanding

Comment: In your case, the issue is that aggregation in the subquery is different from the aggregation in the outer query, so no rows match.